# Why does my JNI code not successfully find a jthrowable's getMessage method?

Tags: java, exception, java-native-interface

I'm trying to access the message in a jthrowable while handing an exception generated when I fail to find a class.  However, I am unable to access the message ID of getMessage() on the jthrowable object, and I don't know why.  I've tried changing the signature of getMessage to "()Ljava/lang/String" (without the semicolon at the end, but that's necessary, right?) with no joy.  I'm confused as hell about this.  I even tried replacing getMessage with toString, and *that* didn't work.  Obviously I'm doing something trivially wrong here.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
jthrowable java_exception;
jclass java_class;
jmethodID method;

java_exception = (*jEnv)->ExceptionOccurred(jEnv);
assert (java_exception != NULL);
java_class = (*jEnv)->GetObjectClass (jEnv, java_exception);
assert (java_class != NULL);
method = (*jEnv)->GetMethodID (jEnv, java_class, "getMessage", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
if (method == NULL) {
printf ("Seriously, how do I get here?!\n");
(*jEnv)->ExceptionDescribe (jEnv);
return;
}
```

The output of this code (amongst other things) looks like this:

> Seriously, how do I get here?!
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/planet/core360/docgen/Processor

`javap -p -s java.lang.Throwable` gives me this:

> Compiled from "Throwable.java"
>   public class java.lang.Throwable extends java.lang.Object implements java.io.Serializable{
>   ...
>   public java.lang.String getMessage();
>     Signature: ()Ljava/lang/String;
>   ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, so it looks like my problem was that `GetObjectClass` doesn't act the way you'd expect it to on a jthrowable, or at least the results of it are not useful for the purposes of getting methods.  Replacing that portion of the code with this works:

```
java_class = (*jEnv)->FindClass (jEnv, "java/lang/Throwable");
method = (*jEnv)->GetMethodID (jEnv, java_class, "getMessage", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
```

Damnably odd, that.  I hope this helps someone else in the future, though.

Comment: Is it possible that GetObjectClass() doesn't work when an exception is active? Try `(*env)->ExceptionClear(env)` before calling GetObjectClass.

Answer (score 4):

I tried your approach, and it worked for me. A few things though: I'm using the C++ interface (though that shouldn't make a difference), and I'm using Java 6 update 10, x64 edition, on Ubuntu 8.04. Perhaps the Java version and/or platform used will make a difference.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <jni.h>

int
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc != 3) {
        std::fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s class message\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    JavaVM* jvm;
    void* penv;
    JavaVMInitArgs args = {JNI_VERSION_1_6};

    if (jint res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, &penv, &args)) {
        std::fprintf(stderr, "Can's create JVM: %d\n", res);
        return -res;
    }

    JNIEnv* env(static_cast<JNIEnv*>(penv));
    jint vers(env->GetVersion());
    std::printf("JNI version %d.%d\n", vers >> 16, vers & 0xffff);

    env->ThrowNew(env->FindClass(argv[1]), argv[2]);
    jthrowable exc(env->ExceptionOccurred());
    std::printf("Exception: %p\n", exc);
    if (exc) {
        jclass exccls(env->GetObjectClass(exc));
        jclass clscls(env->FindClass("java/lang/Class"));

        jmethodID getName(env->GetMethodID(clscls, "getName", "()Ljava/lang/String;"));
        jstring name(static_cast<jstring>(env->CallObjectMethod(exccls, getName)));
        char const* utfName(env->GetStringUTFChars(name, 0));

        jmethodID getMessage(env->GetMethodID(exccls, "getMessage", "()Ljava/lang/String;"));
        jstring message(static_cast<jstring>(env->CallObjectMethod(exc, getMessage)));
        char const* utfMessage(env->GetStringUTFChars(message, 0));

        std::printf("Exception: %s: %s\n", utfName, utfMessage);
        env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(message, utfMessage);
        env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(name, utfName);
    }
    return -jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
}
```

I've used `jnitest java/lang/InternalError 'Hello, world!'` for my testing; feel free to try with different exception types!